# How to prevent multiple files in JavaScript file input when user chooses and selects another file?

Tags: javascript, html, input, file-io, user-input

I am creating a file input with vanilla JavaScript and I only want to allow a single file to be uploaded.

When the user chooses and selects a file and then clicks upload, the file uploads. However, if the user chooses/selects a file, then re-chooses and re-selects a file, clicking the upload button makes 2 requests and uploads the file twice. If 3 files are chosen, this happens 3 times, and so on. The multiple requests are really messing things up on my server. I need to allow only 1 file uploaded when the upload button is clicked, no matter if the user has re-chosen a file. Here is some test code showing this behavior:

```
// Create upload button
const upload_button = document.createElement('button')
upload_button.innerHTML = 'upload'

// Create input for image upload
const upload_input = document.createElement('input')
upload_input.setAttribute('type', 'file');
upload_input.setAttribute('accept', 'image/*');

// Do something when input changes, such as previewing the selected image to be uploaded
upload_input.addEventListener('change', () => {
    console.log('change detected, file likely added')

    // Upload the file selected by the input when upload button is pressed
    upload_button.addEventListener('click', () => {
        console.log('uploading: ', upload_input.files[0])
    })
})

document.querySelector('#about-view').append(upload_input, upload_button)
```

How do I prevent multiple files from being uploaded, even if the user chooses and then re-chooses? Is it possible to select only one file of upload_input.files[0]? Why does the upload request happen more than once?

Edit:

If I move the click event handler outside, how do I access something from the click event that is created by the change event? This is why I originally had the click event inside the change event. Example:

```
// Create upload button
const upload_button = document.createElement('button')
upload_button.innerHTML = 'upload'

// Create input for image upload
const upload_input = document.createElement('input')
upload_input.setAttribute('type', 'file');
upload_input.setAttribute('accept', 'image/*');

// Do something when input changes, such as previewing the selected image to be uploaded
upload_input.addEventListener('change', () => {
    console.log('change detected, file likely added')
    const something = "something"
})

// Upload the file selected by the input when upload button is pressed
upload_button.addEventListener('click', () => {
   console.log('uploading: ', upload_input.files[0])
   console.log(`do something with ${something}`)
})
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is you set the `button` `click` event inside the `input` `change` event, that's made on every `input` change happens, `click` event is duplicated, so you need to move the `click` event handler outside.

```
// Create upload button
const upload_button = document.createElement('button')
upload_button.innerHTML = 'upload'

// Create input for image upload
const upload_input = document.createElement('input')
upload_input.setAttribute('type', 'file');
upload_input.setAttribute('accept', 'image/*');
let something;

// Do something when input changes, such as previewing the selected image to be uploaded
upload_input.addEventListener('change', () => {
    something = 'something'
    console.log('change detected, file likely added')
})

    // Upload the file selected by the input when upload button is pressed
upload_button.addEventListener('click', () => {
   console.log(something)
   console.log('uploading: ', upload_input.files[0])
})

document.querySelector('#about-view').append(upload_input, upload_button)
```

Comment: I see this solves the duplication issue, but what if I create a variable inside the change event that I want to access in the click event? I have edited my post with an example.

Comment: Just declare the variable outside the event listener callback, and assign its value inside it, I just update the answer code, please, check again.